# Removing duplicate records based on hierarchy using arcpy and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, arcpy

I'm attempting to flag duplicate records and delete them using a data dictionary with an arcpy update cursor, and I'm running into dictionary issues.

Essentially, my code iterates through the attribute table and adds a dictionary entry of FACE_ID:CHNG_TYPE for each new FACE_ID. If it encounters a FACE_ID that's already in the dictionary, it compares the CHNG_TYPE of the duplicate FACE_IDs to see which should be deleted (I've left the weighted comparison out as it isn't the issue).

To compare them, the cursor pulls the first change (change_a) CHNG_TYPE directly from the cursor row it's in. It also pulls the FACE_ID so that it can query the dictionary to get the CHNG_TYPE for the other FACE_ID.

When I print the dictionary, it looks like what I would expect. However, **change_b = dict[row[0]] is calculating to be the same value every time**, and I'm not sure why.

When I create the dictionary using this code but leave out the elif statement, I can pull the change_b value accurately with dict[FACE_ID].

Code below, and any help is appreciated!

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['FACE_ID', 'CHNG_TYPE', 'RELATE']) as cursor:
        dict = {}
        for row in cursor:
                if row[0] in dict:
                        change_a = row[1]
                        change_b = dict[row[0]]
                        print(change_a + ' ' + change_b)
                elif row[0] not in dict:
                        dict[row[0]] = row[1]
```

To give an example, this statement creates the dictionary and returns the expected value:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['FACE_ID', 'CHNG_TYPE', 'RELATE']) as cursor:
        dict = {}
        for row in cursor:
                if row[0] not in dict:
                        dict[row[0]] = row[1]
dict[123456]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Delete Identical function or the Find Identical function available in ArcGIS Pro?

```
arcpy.management.DeleteIdentical(in_dataset, fields, {xy_tolerance}, {z_tolerance})

arcpy.management.FindIdentical(in_dataset, out_dataset, fields, {xy_tolerance}, {z_tolerance}, {output_record_option})
```

It could be a faster and more cost-effective solution than your way.

Comment: It turns out this won't work, since it only identifies/deletes duplicates. I need to evaluate which of the duplicates should be deleted based on additional criteria.